# Symfony 5 - Unable to update encoder for User#ID because the credentials have already been cleared

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

This is within a Symfony 5.4 application using its new authenticators system.

On attempting login, there is a warning:

```
Unable to update encoder for User#12345 because the credentials have already been cleared
```

What does this warning mean? (I apologize for not having more to show, but I don't know what "an encoder for a user", or "clearing credentials", refers to in the authentication process.. I'd appreciate any pointers in the right direction)

EDIT- To clarify, the warning does not break functionality. I can log in, etc, everything seems to work. But I'd still like to understand what the warning means.

Comment: did you check or change your configuration security.yml ? do you even use `symfony/security` ? there is not much information here

Comment: @johnSmith I said I'm using the new authenticators system so I feel like I already answered your questions... My question is what does the error message mean at all? Like what is a "user encoder" and what does that mean. What does "credentials have already been cleared" mean, who is clearing that, what is supposed to happen when it works correctly?

Comment: Edited question with correction - this was a warning, not error. Anyway to answer your questions explicitly - yes, security.yml was updated in accordance to new auth system and everything is working correctly. It's massive and not something I want to repost in public. I am not aware of a way to use the new authenticators system without `symfony/security`. The warning doesn't break functionality but I'd like to understand what it means.